# How can I have two foreign keys in a table?(SQL-Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE USERINFO(
    USERID CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PW CHAR(20),
    POINT INT DEFAULT 5000,
    PRIMARY KEY(USERID)
);

CREATE TABLE MESSAGE(
    NO INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    WRITER CHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    RECEIVER CHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    CONTENT CHAR(100),  
    PRIMARY KEY(NO),
    FOREIGN KEY(WRITER) REFERENCES USERINFO(USERID) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(RECEIVER) REFERENCES USERINFO(USERID) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

This is error code.

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 125 Introducing FOREIGN KEY
> constraint 'FK__MESSAGE__RECEIVE__379B24DB' on table 'MESSAGE' may
> cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
> ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 125 Could not create constraint or
> index. See previous errors.

I know I'm completely wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `NO` is a bit weird column name. (Also an ANSI SQL reserved word, i.e. may cause migration issues. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.)

Comment: It (`NO`) is also a reserved [ODBC keyword and future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#odbc-reserved-keywords) and a [Future Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#future-keywords), so really should be avoided as an object name, in my opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server error: introducing foreign key constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763244/sql-server-error-introducing-foreign-key-constraint-on-table-may-cause-cycles-o)

Comment: Do NOT store plain-text passwords in a database. It is highly unlikely that a message can exist without both writer and sender - none of those columns should be nullable..